# Makefiles to include multiple headers in c

Tags: c, makefile

I originally had this in my makefile:

```
all:
    gcc myFunctions1.h myFunctions1.c myFunctions2.h myFunctions2.c main.c -o main
```

which worked for some reason until I restarted the terminal. Now I get this error:

```
clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
```

So what's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't specify header files when compiling. You don't need to as they are included in the source files, and can't be used by themselves.

You might also want to learn about [translation units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29), and how they relate to source and header files.